# number of rows limit that can be displayed in jsf

Tags: java, mysql, jsf

I develop jsf application. I have a MySQL Student table consists of 30-40 column and 600 rows. Here is the code in StudentBean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "student")
@SessionScoped
public class StudentBean implements Serializable{

private List<Student> studentlist = new ArrayList<Student>();
private Student student = new Student();
private HtmlDataTable datatable;
private HtmlInputHidden studentnpm = new HtmlInputHidden();
private String querybynpm;
private String querybyangkatan;
private String status;
private String result;

public String init() {

    try {
        Class.forName(JurusanConection.getDriver());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }


    try {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(JurusanConection.getUrl(),
                JurusanConection.getUser_name(), JurusanConection.getPass_word());

        String query = "SELECT * FROM student";
        Statement ps = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(query);

        while (rs.next()) {
            Student students = new Student();
            students.setNpm(rs.getString("npm"));
            students.setNama(rs.getString("nama").toString());
            //setter and getter 
            students.setTanggalregistrasi(rs.getString("tanggalregistrasi").toString());
            students.setDosenwali(rs.getString("dosenwali").toString());
            students.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
            students.setKelas(rs.getString("kelas"));
            studentlist.add(students);
        }
        result="mahasiswa";
        ps.close();
        con.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        setResult(null);
        setStatus(e.getMessage());
    }
    return result;
}
```

I didn't populate database via constructor, but calling the init() method. I got an error message javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException. However when I modify the query to limit the number displayed by 150 row, no error. Can anybody figure out how to display this 600 rows without error. Thank you...

Comment: And where are you calling `init` method. Perhaps you wanted to annotate method with `@PostConstruct` to populate your list?

Comment: Why don't you tell what is `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably getting NullPointerExceptions at the following unsafe lines of code:

```
rs.getString("nama").toString()
rs.getString("tanggalregistrasi").toString()
rs.getString("dosenwali").toString()
```

This makes the assumption that there will **never** be a null value for those three columns in your recordset.  You should assign this to a variable and do a null check before using the `.` operator.

Furthermore, why are you calling toString() here?  `ResultSet.getString` method already returns a String object.  This is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @partlov : init() is called from mahasiswa.xhtml and will be displayed also in mahasiswa.xhtml.

Comment: @BalusC : Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at beans.StudentBean.init(StudentBean.java:61)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

Comment: yes, after I removed all .toString() in ResultSet, all rows were populated and displayed in web page. I checked there are several columns that contain null values. Thank you guys, problem solved